# devise 'user_path' error when redirecting after log-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I used this code block in devise,from https://coderwall.com/p/djgkag, to return the users where they came from after a successful login:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session.fetch 'user_return_to', user_path
end
```

But i get an error that says:

> NameError in SessionsController#create
>   undefined local variable or method `user_path' for #

How will I define user_path? or how will i replace it? I've run rake routes and its not there indeed.

Comment: define it in you routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and do the following:

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
  session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
end
```

With this you can then call this in your controller by doing `redirect_to session[:return_to]`. If that does not work, take a look at [How To: Redirect back to current page after sign in, sign out, sign up, update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update). Which should detail what your after. But try the way I suggested first.

Comment: I already tried using request.referer but the problem is, when the user makes an error when typing his password, the page reloads again then it already becomes the request.referer which causes an error. I tried using conditions to detect the host name or port number in my local machine. But it didn't work the request.referer still gets assigned to my session[:return_to].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should redirect to edit_user_registration_path.

Devise does not provide any profil page by default.